# how to trigger the increment only once

Tags: javascript

I have used the `setTimeout` function so my object stays on `y<0` for a while and at that time i want to my increment to trigger only once but it keeps on triggering ...more i delay my function using the `setTimeout` function higher times the increment operation gets trigger......so what is the solution through which my increment triggers only once no matter how long my object stays in `y<0`

```
Player.prototype.checkInWater = function () {
     if (this.y < 0) {
       ++scoreGot
       setTimeout(function(){  
         player.x = 202;
         nplayer.y = 405;
       }, 300);
    }
};
```

Comment: How's `checkInWater` called?

Comment: That's well-nigh impossible to debug without a concise yet meaningful example of the control logic responsible for calling `Player.prototype.checkInWater`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Player = function(){
     ....
     this.checkedInWater = false;
}
Player.prototype.checkInWater = function () {
     if (this.y < 0 && !this.checkedInWater) {
       ++scoreGot;
       t = this;
       t.checkedInWater = true;

       setTimeout(function(){  
         player.x = 202;
         nplayer.y = 405;
         t.checkedInWater = false;
       }, 300);
    }
};
```